# Python3 buildout error on BOSS (Billing for OpenStack Software)

Tags: python-3.x, openstack, buildout

I'm trying to install BOSS (Billing for OpenStack Software) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. (Using Python 3.4)

this is what i got when i try to `buildout -c backend.cfg`

```
/opt/boss$ sudo bin/buildout -c backend.cfg
While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1995, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 507, in install
    self._load_extensions()
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1039, in _load_extensions
    ep.load()(self)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2258, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/buildout.eggscleaner-0.1.7-py3.4.egg/buildout/eggscleaner/__init__.py", line 70
    print "Can't remove path %s: %s" % (path, e)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just followed the installation doc in source file.
anybody can help me to solve this?

you can download this project on https://github.com/asdfolks/boss

Thanks.

++ one more question.

I successed to build the first one (buildout -c backend.cfg), but got almost same problem on next installation step.

```
Installing frontend-admin.
/tmp/tmpj61mn5xj/run: 1: cd: can't cd to frontend/admin/apps/data-pro-admin
npm WARN package.json angular-perfect-scrollbar@0.0.5 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json eslint-plugin-class-property@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package eslint does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-config-standard@5.3.5 wants eslint@>=2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-plugin-class-property@0.0.2 wants eslint@^2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-eslint@5.0.4 wants eslint@<2.3.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-loader@1.5.0 wants eslint@>=1.6.0 <4.0.0

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/boss
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/boss/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
While:
  Installing frontend-admin.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1995, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 666, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/zc.buildout-2.5.3-py3.4.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1410, in _call
    return f()
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/collective.recipe.cmd-0.11-py3.4.egg/collective/recipe/cmd/__init__.py", line 56, in install
    self.execute()
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/collective.recipe.cmd-0.11-py3.4.egg/collective/recipe/cmd/__init__.py", line 69, in execute
    run_commands(cmds, self.shell)
  File "/opt/boss/.buildout/eggs/collective.recipe.cmd-0.11-py3.4.egg/collective/recipe/cmd/__init__.py", line 39, in run_commands
    check_call('%s %s' % (shell, tmpfile), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 561, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sh /tmp/tmpj61mn5xj/run' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Of course i edited the `base.cfg` like https://github.com/asdfolks/boss/blob/bc0cfe3067bf1cbf26789f7443a36e7cdd2ac869/base.cfg#L19-L21 this. So, there was no error occurred on `buildout -c backend`. but occurred when i tried to `buildout -c frontend`.

need your hand to solve this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the `buildout.eggscleaner` seems to be not python 3 compatible.

Without any knowledge about this project, I think you should try remove this dependency from the buildout config.

Remove those lines...
https://github.com/asdfolks/boss/blob/bc0cfe3067bf1cbf26789f7443a36e7cdd2ac869/base.cfg#L19-L21

... and try again.

Comment: Yes, the eggscleaner extension has a `print something` statement, which should be a `print(something)` function call in python 3.

Comment: I added one more problem on the article. Could you please check it for me?

Comment: pls ask a new question... I'm not able to help for the second one